# Cloud confluent kafka installation failed in ubuntu 18

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

Instruction page says as:-

1. Install the Confluent Cloud CLI
   Run this command to install the Confluent Cloud CLI.
   curl -L --http1.1 https://cnfl.io/ccloud-cli | sh -s -- -b /usr/local/bin

it failed for permission

> "install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/ccloud':
>   Permission denied"

Even if I tried

```
sudo curl -L --http1.1 https://cnfl.io/ccloud-cli | sh -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
```

Same error. How do I install it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I installed it as:-

```
curl -L --http1.1 https://cnfl.io/ccloud-cli | sh -s -- -b ~/Downloads/
```

After the above command

```
sudo mv  ~/Downloads/ccloud /usr/local/bin/
```

Everything is fine now.

Comment: If you want this as a one-liner, the `sudo` has to go in front of the `sh`, not in front of the `curl` -- that is the issue with what the OP tried.